# Where to find extension-printer.dll

Tags: php

I have tried using the printer methods but I get errors when whenever I use them. Have searched the web and the solution was to install the printer.dll file but I have failed to get this file.

forexample I get this for printer_list function

Call to undefined function printer_list()

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://php.net/manual/fa/printer.installation.php

> This » PECL extension is not bundled with PHP.
>
> Windows users must enable `php_printer.dll` inside of php.ini in order to use these functions. A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the [building on Windows section](http://php.net/manual/fa/install.windows.building.php).

You can find the currently available DLLs at

- http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/

Printer does not have an official release, but there is snapshot release available at

- http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/

You need to find the right one for the PHP version you are using. As you can tell by the file names, these DLLs are for 5.3 to 5.5 - if you need it for a different PHP version, you need to build it yourself.